# How to query rows created in a stored procedure in an outer query or cte

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to retrieve a row inserted by a stored procedure, but the row is not available until the next query.  A quick example of what I'm trying to do is below:

```
create table testsp(
  id serial primary key,
  name text
);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION save(_id int DEFAULT null, _name text DEFAULT 'hi') returns int as $$
DECLARE
  _out int;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO testsp(name) values(_name) returning id into _out;
  RETURN _out;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

-- calling save will return the id of the inserted row
select save(_name:='foo');
 save 
------
    1
(1 row)

-- but using in an outer query, the row is not visible but was inserted
with savecte AS(select save(_name:='foo') as id) select * from testsp join savecte on testsp.id=savecte.id;
 id | name | id 
----+------+----
(0 rows)

-- same result using subquery
select * from testsp where id in(select save(_name:='foo'));)
 id | name 
----+------
(0 rows)
```

Comment: In terms of the PostgreSQL innards concerned, you'd need to find a way to get PostgreSQL to increment the *command counter* after evaluating the inner CTE term. It does this for writeable CTEs, but it doesn't know that your procedure performs writes, so it won't increment the command counter. Off the top of my head not sure how to deal with this other than using two separate statements or using a writeable CTE directly.

Comment: @CraigRinger thx, a quick hack that worked for me is wrapping my select in another function -- I'm writing a new app and using stored procs for the dal layer but now reconsidering if I shouldn't just go gang busters with CTE's in the app, the point being to cut down the chatter between the app and the db.

Comment: Using `DO` blocks or functions is often preferable. With a decent client interface like PgJDBC you can also issue batches of statements that only incur a single round trip - but unfortunately most other database interfaces don't seem to provide much in the way of batching support.